# How to fetch parent values

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, persistence

I am trying to work on JPA for the first time and kind a confuse how can i fetch parent values.

Here are my table structure

```
T1(
   id (pk),
   name (varchar)
)

T2(
  id (pk),
  t1_id (fk_t1),
  number (int)
)

T3 (
  id (pk),
  t2_id (fk_t2),
  time (datetime)
  zone (tinyint),
  name (varchar)
)
```

If i have to work in SQL, I can use this query

```
select * from T3, T2, T1
where T3.time = <given_time>,
and T3.name = <given_name>,
and T3.t2_id = T2.id,
and T2.t1_id = T1.id
```

Now, How can I transfer this to a JPA. I can use the named query, that's not the problem. But how should i structure the object.

So far I have this

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T3, schema="", catalog="dbname")
public class T3Entity{
    private int id;
    private DateTime datetime;
    private int zone;
    private String name;

   @Id
   @Column(name="id", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)
   //GETTER/SETTERS

   @Basic
   @Column(name="datetime", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)
   //GETTER/SETTERS

   @Basic
   @Column(name="zone", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)
   //GETTER/SETTERS

   @Basic
   @Column(name="name", nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)
   //GETTER/SETTERS

}
```

Now here i am confused. Shall I create another Field called `T2` (parent field in every child) and then annotate ? how to annotate ? Would the custom query automatically set the values of those objects ?

Answer (score 0):

You will also need Entity classes for tables T1 and T2, e.g. T1Entity and T2Entity.

In T3Entity add a member with type T2Entity and annotate with @ManyToOne:

```
public class T3Entity {
     ...old fields...

     @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name="t2_id")
     private T2Entity t2;  

     // getter, setter
}
```

Start [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToOne) to read about this annotation.

Comment: How would i write the query ? Given that I have `T2Entity` in `T3Entity` I can't use `T3Entity.id = T2Entity.id` ??????

Comment: You use JPA joins: `SELECT t1,t2,t3 FROM T1Entity t1 JOIN t1.t2 t2 JOIN t2.t3 t3 WHERE t3.time = :time and t3.name = :name`, see http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#FROM_Clause